# d3js nice() not rounding up axis domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've added a [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/H8Ga2erSndvhdoQFKjmR?p=preview) here, if you select team 2 in the dropdown the domain will be set to 9 and not what I'd expect it to be, which is 10.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_nice) it states the following about `nice()`

> Extends the domain so that it starts and ends on nice round values.

and further down if you have a dynamic domain it says:

> You must re-nice the scale after setting the new domain, if desired.

How do I achieve this? I Thought that having the `.domain().nice()` in my update function would fix this? Or is this a floating point issue somehow, since all numbers in javascript is 64-bit floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9 is a round number!

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/7e40ca7fcdeb3ca31b2631064c80840378ac30c6/src/nice.js#L15), you'll see that the *"rounding"* is just using `interval.floor` and `interval.ceil`:

```
domain[i0] = interval.floor(x0);
domain[i1] = interval.ceil(x1);
```

This being the `interval` object:

```
{
  floor: function(x) { return pows(Math.floor(logs(x))); },
  ceil: function(x) { return pows(Math.ceil(logs(x))); }
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to round up to the nearest ten, just do:

```
xO.domain([0, 
    Math.ceil(d3.max(data, d => Math.max(
        d["old" + input], d["new" + input]
    ))/10)*10
]).nice();
```

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8rFeodCk0Jj74JT5osJy?p=preview